# Creating file name for creating a file does not seem to work

Tags: php, html, forms

When creating and posting just the user note data, I had no issues. Yet when I attempt to allow the user to specify the file name, the code refuses to run.

Is there another method of approaching this problem or is my syntax off?

HTML:

```
<form method="post">                                                                                   
<div>                                                                                              
 <div style="margin-right 5px">                                                                    
    <input type="text" name="noteData" id="notes" size="250">                                      
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" class="txtNote_But" value="Save Text 
 Note">                 
 </div>                                                                                            

        <input type="text" class="fileName" name="fileName" id="fileName" 
        size="35">               
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit2" class="filName_But" value="Save 
        File Name">            

 </div>                                                                                            
 </form>           

PHP WRITE:

$noteName = $_POST['fileName'];                                        
$noteData = $_POST['notes'];                                           

$notes = fopen('' + $noteName,"wb");                                   
fwrite($notes,$noteData);                                              
fclose($notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have **two submit buttons on one page** which causes only one input field to get posted.

1. Restructure your form to something like this:

```html
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <div style="margin-right:5px;">
      <input type="text" class="fileName" name="fileName" id="fileName" size="35" value="untitled">
      <input type="text" name="noteData" id="notes" size="250">
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

2. Get the POST data in your php script:

```
    $noteName = $_POST['fileName'];                                        
    $noteData = $_POST['notes'];                                           

    $notes = fopen('' + $noteName,"wb");                                   
    fwrite($notes,$noteData);                                              
    fclose($notes);
```

By the way using the textarea tag would be more suitable for the note input:

```html
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <div style="margin-right:5px;">
      <input type="text" class="fileName" name="fileName" id="fileName" size="35" value="untitled"><br>
      <textarea type="text" name="noteData" id="notes"></textarea><br>
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If I use textarea would this mean I would be able to specify the height of the input field? As another large issue I had was that my input field would only be 1 row in height no matter what I tried

Comment: Yes, you would be able to just the same way you do with a div. You can read more about the textarea tag here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file_put_contents()` instead of `fwrite()`

Example

```
// Create a unique prefix to prevent duplicate file names
$noteNamePrefix = $prefix = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 1).substr(md5(time()),1);

$noteName = $_POST['fileName'];                                        
$noteData = $_POST['notes']; 

// Write File To Disk (Replace _PATH_TO_DIR With the destination path Eg /public_html/uploads/)
file_put_contents(_PATH_TO_DIR_.$noteNamePrefix.$noteName, $noteData);
```